# Calculate the Jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(s, t)}(-1,2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Consider the next  transformations
$$
S:\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x=u^{2}-v^{2}\\y=3uv & and \quad T:\left\{\begin{array}{l}
u=t^{2}-s+s t \\
v=s^{2}-\frac{2 s}{t}-3
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Calculate the Jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(s, t)}(-1,2)$

What should I do?

do $x=(t^2-s+st)^{2}-(s^2-\frac{2s}{t}-2)^2$ and

$y=3(t^2-s+st)(s^2-\frac{2s}{t}-2)^2$

and then build the matrix $2\times2$ with the partials respect $s$ and $t$ of $x=(t^2-s+st)^{2}-(s^2-\frac{2s}{t}-2)^2$ and $y=3(t^2-s+st)(s^2-\frac{2s}{t}-2)^2$ ?

what I mean

$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$ in $(-1,2)=$

$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 17\\
-30 & \frac{-27}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$

is right?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely a correct way to go about this problem. Note that what you did is apply the chain rule for a scalar function multiple times. This is equivalent to using the chain rule for Jacobian-style derivatives as

$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (s,t)} = \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (s,t)} = \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial s}  &  \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \\  \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial s} &  \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\end{bmatrix}\; .$$

Once again, you are completely correct in your approach but I want to provide a slightly different way to compute it that you may find more elegant.